# beautify the url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Hi my site url is like

https://example.com/articleDesc.php?post=paleo-diet-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-so-popular

I want to modify this url as

https://example.com/paleo-diet-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-so-popular

But i want to use this query string value to get the respnse

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I tried this  RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^articleDesc.php/(.*)/(.*)$ articleDesc.php/?post=$1 [QSA]

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /articleDesc.php?post=$1 [L]
```